# Located element in a dropdown list but can not click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

There is a dropdown list I want to click, it has four options when expanded. With my code, I can click and expand this dropdown list, but unable to click on the option (value = '100').

This is the HTML code for the elements I want to click before the dropdown list is expanded:

[image: HTML code before dropdown list is expanded]

This is the HTML code for the elements I want to click after the dropdown list is expanded:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
//@FunctionName : Display100ResultsPerPage
//@Description  : A function that chooses to display 100 results per page instead of 10
//@Parameters   : PageObj: page that displays items
//@Returns      : None
//@Version      : v1.0
function Display100ResultsPerPage ( PageObj )
{
    var localPageObj = PageObj;
    var display100ItemsPerPageOptionCssSelector = "div[class='per-page-section'] select option[value='100']";
    var displayNItemsPerPageDropdownListCssSelector = "div[class='per-page-section'] select";

    localPageObj.QuerySelector(displayNItemsPerPageDropdownListCssSelector).Click();
    aqUtils.Delay(500);
    localPageObj.QuerySelector(display100ItemsPerPageOptionCssSelector).Click();
}
```

My code manages to:

- Clicks and expands the dropdown list, but unable to click on the (100) option.

If I add an additional line in my code:

```
Log.Message(localPageObj.QuerySelector(display100ItemsPerPageOptionCssSelector).getAttribute('value'));
```

I got a logging message saying "100", which means my code can successfully locate this (100) option but why can not I click on it?

Many thanks

I have tried the following approach:

```
localPageObj.contentDocument.Script.jQuery("div[class='per-page-section'] select").find("option").css("z-index","999", "position", "relative");
```

option elements have changed into:
[image]

By index, I tried to click on the last `option (value = '100')`, but still not working.

Comment: try putting alert on click of select element also please check if calling Delay() causing any issue

Comment: can be an css issue?? Try setting `z-index:999;position:relative` on  `option` of that `select` element

Comment: @TechBreak, no, it is not the Delay(). Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @NishanthMatha, I tried, it did not work.

Comment: update the OP with what you tried!

Comment: @NishanthMatha, please take a look at the updated OP. thanks.

Comment: where is the `position:relative` bit?? without `position` bit `z-index` will not work. So, try : `z-index:999;position:relative`

Comment: @NishanthMatha, thanks, will do

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the element by right clicking on it, if the inspector takes you to a different element I think you need to give dropdown list a "z-index" and remember that z-index works only when you specify position to relative or absolute. that should solve the problem, I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not possible for me to inspect this "100" option element. As soon as I click "inspect element" option or use ctrl + shift + c combo to enter inspection mode, this drop down list will collapse.